# System Ruby installation has no GEM_HOME

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm using RVM but a lot of times when I run a gem related terminal command such as that below from one of my Ruby installations

```
rvm gemdir
```

I receive this error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown environment option [/usr/local/bin]
```

I should add that I get the same error (twice in fact) when I run the same command from the system installation of Ruby.

I noticed that when I switched back from one of my RVM installed Rubies to the system version (I'm running OSX 10.15.4 Catalina) and run 'env'

```
rvm system
env
```

I don't see an entry for GEM_HOME or GEM_PATH that is present in my RVM Ruby installations.

Is this significant and is it a cause of the error that I'm getting? If so, can I fix it?

Edit: after running

```
echo $PATH
```

the following was the output

```
/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global/bin:/Users/Andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/Users/Andy/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The only installed version of Ruby via rvm is 2.6.5 which I've designated by default. Obviously the system version is still there too.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.rvm && \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` then reinstall Ruby.

Comment: If things are really borked, anothermh has the right idea. Burn it to the ground and rebuild.

Comment: Would reinstalling RVM fix my system installation of ruby? Or is it RVM that’s causing my problem?

Comment: can you do a "rvm list", "rvm use <one version of ruby>" and then "gem env"?

Comment: So I removed and reinstalled, still have similar errors and gem env is giving me ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown environment option [/usr/local/bin] again.

Comment: Most RVM errors are caused by a misconfigured `PATH` variable. Please do `echo $PATH` and add it to your question.